# Create a Custom Path to Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives, paths

To get at archive pages (by default) the path is /%category%/  Which is fine. But how would i change it to have a static string prefix before the category variable (e.g. /archive/%category%).

Same thing for custom-post-type archives

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Permalinks and insert `archive` in the Category base field.

For custom post type archives, you can set that to anything you want via the `has_archive` argument of `register_post_type`:

```
'has_archive' => 'archive/your-post-type'
```

Comment: How do i do the has_archive thing? I use the Custom Post Types plugin to manage all my custom post types....

Comment: Also, I don't think the Category base field worked....  how would i then visit said archive?

Comment: (sorry, the Custom Post Type UI plugin)

Comment: *How do i do the has_archive thing? I use the Custom Post Types plugin to manage all my custom post types.* If that plugin doesn't have the option to set archive slug, then you'll have to add the post types manually. *how would i then visit said archive?* i'm not sure what you mean? any links to category pages will point to the new URL.